# Neo4j Show Only Specific Relations in the Browser Graph View

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this Cypher query:

```
MATCH (i:Issue {name:"SN-229"})-[d:ON_DATE]->(s:Stage)
RETURN i,(MAX(d.long)-MIN(d.long)+1) AS Days,s
```

and I get these results in the Neo4j Browser's Text view
[image]
Which are the answers I want.

But when I view the result in the Neo4j Browser's Graph view, it insists on displaying the individual dates in the relationships!?!?
[image: Neo4j Graph View]

What query could I write to show me this "ideal" Graph view *(the displayed dates are the MIN(d.long) dates)* or at ***least*** just display the relationship with the MIN date?

[image]

This query will return all of the required info for my ideal Graph view, but again, it insists on displaying ***all*** of the relations *(and I don't know how to modify the caption for the relationship, via the query, to add the 'X Days' to the relation's displayed date)*:

```
MATCH (i:Issue {name:"SN-229"})-[d:ON_DATE]->(s:Stage) RETURN i,MIN(d),(MAX(d.long)-MIN(d.long)+1) AS Days,s
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the option "Connect result nodes" is checked, Neo4j browser will connect the resultant nodes in the graph visualization mode when a connection between these nodes exist.

To disable this behavior you should go to the section "Graph Visualization" of Neo4j Browser Settings and uncheck the option "Connect result nodes" as show in the image below:

[image: Graph visualization options]

Comment: Ah man! I played with that but I stupidly didn't think to rerun the query.  I was expecting a dynamic update of the graph!! DOH!


One last question, is there a way for me to add the 'Days' results to the relationship's caption (Days is a calculated value, not a stored value)?

Comment: Hi @Steve. Maybe you can try setting a new property in the relationship. Like this: `MATCH (i:Issue {name:"SN-229"})-[d:ON_DATE]->(s:Stage)
WITH i, d, (MAX(d.long)-MIN(d.long)+1) AS Days,s
SET d.Days = Days
RETURN i, d, s`

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but it makes the attribute permanent (which imposes a time penalty while it updates all the records) - I was really hoping for a non-permanent solution.

If I have the query delete the attribute afterwards then I'll have twice the time penalty (granted, I am not running a mission critical thing here so the time penalty is just for argument's sake and not really something that I would truly have to be concerned about)

Comment: @Steve Well, you can try returning a map projection, but I think that this way the graph visualization mode will not works correctly: `MATCH (i:Issue {name:"SN-229"})-[d:ON_DATE]->(s:Stage)
WITH i, d, (MAX(d.long)-MIN(d.long)+1) AS Days,s
RETURN i, d{.*, days: Days}, s`

Comment: You can order the relationships by day first, and then `return i, s, 
head(collect(d)) as rel`

Comment: Hi @Steve. This answer has helped to solve your issue? If so, can you consider [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419)? This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!