# extracting subgraph without some relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with some accounts and transfers between them. There are several accounts and they have multiple transfers between them. As there are too many transfers I want to create an additional path that is a summary of the transactions. I do this as below:

```
MERGE (s:acc { number: '{sender}'}) 
MERGE(r:acc { number: '{receiver}'})
MERGE (s) - [t:transfer {amount: {amount}, day: date('{date}')} ]-> (r)
MERGE (s)-[tot:total]->(r)
  ON CREATE SET tot.total = t.amount, tot.first = t.day, tot.last = t.day, tot.nr_of_transfers = 1
  ON MATCH SET tot.total = tot.total + t.amount, tot.last = t.day, tot.nr_of_transfers = tot.nr_of_transfers +1
```

That works very nicely indeed. However now I want to get the graph without the transfer relationships. The Graph also contains many other relationships such as `owns`, `knows` etc. I would thus like to exclude only relationships of type `transfer` from the result. How do I achieve that?

I've tried (unsuccessfully):

```
match p = (n)-[t]-()
where type(t) <> "transfer"
return p limit 25
```

That query gives sort of what i need but it also return the empty data and thus displays the `transfer` relationships in the browser and he table.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50065971/4989460

Comment: Excellent thanks, is this also possible for just certain types of relationships (transfers) in my case?

Comment: Not. But you can try like this: `where NOT type(t) IN ["transfer", "type1", "type2"] ...`